# Set permissions of a directory to be owned by Everyone with all access

Tags: winapi

I need to change the permissions of a directory to be owned by the Everyone user with all access rights on this directory.  I'm a bit new to the Win32 API, so I'm somewhat lost in the SetSecurity* functions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
SetSecurityInfo(hDir, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This will give all permissions to all users for the given directory handle.

Comment: This is really dangerous. It removes all access control and security settings! Much better to follow the answer on this post for allowing full control to the "Users" group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690780/how-to-create-directory-with-all-rights-granted-to-everyone

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is a good idea?  I spend a lot of time removing public access (especially public write access) from files and directories on Unix systems, in part because allowing anyone to remove or add files to a directory is an open invitation to abuse.

Comment: It is actually a good idea, if file/folder must be accessible by everyone.

Comment: Making something writable by everyone can be quite different from removing all security and access controls, which is what the above does.