# How to create directory with all rights granted to everyone

Tags: windows, security, winapi, directory, directory-security

I need to programmatically create a directory that grants "Full Control" to the group "Everyone".  If I use

```
CreateDirectory(path, NULL);
```

This will, according to the Win32 SDK [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa363855.aspx), create a directory that inherits from its parent directory.  I do not want to inherit the access rights of the parent directory I need to ensure that "Everyone" has full control over the directory.

Obviously, this will require setting up the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure with the appropriate security descriptor.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 14):

Here's one technique that seems to work:

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
PSID everyone_sid = NULL;
AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &everyone_sid);

EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
ea.grfAccessPermissions = SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL | STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL;
ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea.Trustee.ptstrName  = (LPWSTR)everyone_sid;

PACL acl = NULL;
SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, NULL, &acl);

PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                                   SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sd, TRUE, acl, FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

CreateDirectory(path, &sa);

FreeSid(everyone_sid);
LocalFree(sd);
LocalFree(acl);
```

Note that this sample code has absolutely no error checking -- you'll have to supply that yourself.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot for this piece of code. I've been trying to figure out why my game keeps crashing when creating a directory in user specific app data folder. Your code saved me - no more crashes.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the following code snippet as it creates a folder inheriting default rights - which seems the right thing to do - other software / the user might have setup specific inheritable rights on a directory for a legitimate reason - then adds a Full Control explicit access entry for the built in "Users" group.

```
BOOL CreateDirectoryWithUserFullControlACL(LPCTSTR lpPath)
{
  if(!CreateDirectory(lpPath,NULL))
    return FALSE;

  HANDLE hDir = CreateFile(lpPath,READ_CONTROL|WRITE_DAC,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
  if(hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return FALSE; 

  ACL* pOldDACL;
  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR* pSD = NULL;
  GetSecurityInfo(hDir, SE_FILE_OBJECT , DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, (void**)&pSD);

  PSID pSid = NULL;
  SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY authNt = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
  AllocateAndInitializeSid(&authNt,2,SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS,0,0,0,0,0,0,&pSid);

  EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea={0};
  ea.grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
  ea.grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
  ea.grfInheritance = CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE|OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE;
  ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
  ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
  ea.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pSid;

  ACL* pNewDACL = 0;
  DWORD err = SetEntriesInAcl(1,&ea,pOldDACL,&pNewDACL);

  if(pNewDACL)
    SetSecurityInfo(hDir,SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);

  FreeSid(pSid);
  LocalFree(pNewDACL);
  LocalFree(pSD);
  LocalFree(pOldDACL);
  CloseHandle(hDir);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use [SetSecurityInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379588(VS.85).aspx)

In the description of the optional *pDacl* argument:

> ... If the value of the SecurityInfo parameter includes the DACL-SECURITY-INFORMATION flag and the value of this parameter is set to NULL, full access to the object is granted to everyone.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that uses a non-null and correctly initialized SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE with the CreateDirectory() call.

Comment: I had code that was accidentally setting a NULL DACL, and with UAC on, the final result didnt equal all users full control.